# How can I make a reference to a Glossary that typesets as \glossarytoctitle?

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package. I created a custom glossary called `foo` with the title, "My Foo Glossary Title":

```
\newglossary[fgg]{foo}{fgs}{fgo}{My Foo Glossary}
```

Ideally, I'd like to make a reference to this glossary in my text using `\nameref` or `\autoref`, such that it looks like "...please see My Foo Glossary." via something resembling the following code:

```
...please see \nameref{foo}.
```

This doesn't work....

I understand that I needed to add a label to the glossary in order to reference it (isn't it already labelled somehow -- it has to have a label if it is on the Table of Contents page, right?). I redefined the `\glossarypreamble` macro as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{%
\label{\currentglossary}%
}
```

Then I was able to link to it as follows:

```
...please see \autoref{foo}.
```

Trouble is, this produces the text "Appendix A.3" rather than "My Foo Glossary". How can I get the link to display the text equivalent to `\glossarytoctitle`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Absolutely -- and that wasn't a very intrusive way of doing it, either! Thanks so much for your help! :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy it helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary[fgg]{foo}{fgs}{fgo}{My Foo Glossary}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{fooentry}{name={foo entry},description={foo description},type=foo}
\newglossaryentry{mainentry}{name={main entry},description={main description}}

\begin{document}

\noindent \Gls{fooentry} is an entry from \nameref{glo:foo}, while \gls{mainentry} is an entry from \nameref{glo:main}.

\bigskip

\printglossary[type=foo]
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabelname{\@glotype@foo@title}
\label{glo:foo}
\makeatother

\printglossary[type=main]
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabelname{\@glotype@main@title}
\label{glo:main}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The trick is to use a separate `\printglossary` for each glossary and to add, after each of them, e.g. after the "foo" glossary, the code

```
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabelname{\@glotype@foo@title}
\label{glo:foo}
\makeatother
```

and refer to it as `\nameref{glo:foo}`.

Here `\@glotype@foo@title` contains the name of the glossary and `\@currentlabelname` is where the name title for `\nameref` is internally stored.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Version 4.02 (which I've just uploaded to CTAN) now has an extra value for the `numberedsection` package option: `numberedsection=nameref`. This uses an unnumber section (or chapter, depending on the class) but inserts `\label{\glsautoprefix`*type*`}` after the section heading. You may need to wait a few days before the new version appears in the TeX distributions, but once it's available you can do:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedsection=nameref]{glossaries}

\newglossary[fgg]{foo}{fgs}{fgo}{My Foo Glossary}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\newglossaryentry{sample2}{type=foo,name={sample2},description={another example}}

\begin{document}

Reference \gls{sample} and \gls{sample2}.

Reference main glossary: \nameref{main}.

Reference foo glossary: \nameref{foo}.

\printglossaries


\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

(`\glsautoprefix` defaults to nothing, but can be redefined to avoid conflicts with other labels.)