# What is the label of the glossary?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, glossaries

I'd like to add a link to the glossary in my main text.

```
See the \nameref{XXX} on page \ref{XXX}.
```

So far I couldn't find out the name of the label of the glossary. There should be one, since the link in my TOC works. How can I find out the name of the label?

Comment: Hi, please provide an MWE so we can see what packages you are using. If you use `glossaries`, you can just do like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49780

Comment: You can have a look at this one, too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144908/27635

Comment: Upgrade to v4.02 and use `numberedsection=nameref` as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148534/19862

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Can you please write an answer from your comment, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Sven I'm sorry I can't on this question as it's been marked as a duplicate. There's no way of answering once a question has been closed.